# $L^\infty$ decay for the Klein–Gordon equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics, general-relativity

By Fourier transform, the flow of the Klein–Gordon wave flow is $e^{it\sqrt{1-\Delta}}$. That is, if we have initial data $\phi(0,x)=\phi_0(x)$, then the solution will be given by $\phi(t,x)=e^{it\sqrt{1-\Delta}}\phi_0(x)$ or $\hat\phi(t,\xi)=e^{it\sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}}\hat\phi_0(\xi)$ on the Fourier side.

It is clear from this representation that the $L^2$ norm is conserved. I want to prove that the $L^\infty$ norm decays like $t^{-d/2}$.

The way to prove for the Schrodinger equation with wave flow $e^{-it\Delta}$ is to take the inverse Fourier transform $S_t(x):=\mathcal F^{-1}[e^{it|\xi|^2}]$ and show that it decays like $t^{-d/2}$, and then to use Young's inequality: $$\|\phi\|_{L^\infty}=\|S_t*\phi_0\|_{L^\infty}\leq\|S_t\|_{L^\infty}\|\phi_0\|_{L^1}.$$
But I can't seem to do this for the Klein–Gordon equation.

Comment: Look at Example 4 here: https://tricki.sisask.com/article/method_of_stationary_phase. I believe the estimate you want will only hold with some sort of frequency restriction .

Comment: Klein-Gordon estimates are typically broken up into short and long-time estimates. However, I believe that the two main theorems stated in this paper solve your problem. They characterize the operator norm of the semigroup as an operator from $L^p\to L^q$ for both short and long times.

Markovskii, A.I. Remarks on the Lp − Lq estimates of solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation. Ukr Math J 44, 205–214 (1992). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01061744